# What is the difference between Partial and Optional operator in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```
interface I1 {
    x: number;
    y: string;
}

interface I2 {
    x?: number;
    y?: string;
}

const tmp1: Partial<I1> = {}, tmp2: I2 = {};
```

Just like the example, is there an obvious difference between these two things?

Comment: Nope. Partial<I1> and I2 are equivalent.

Comment: `Partial<I1>` is just a way of creating `I2` without having to repeat yourself (and risk them getting out of sync).

Comment: Anyone commenting here want to write an answer, or close this as a duplicate of something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is what is being expressed.

The types of `tmp1` and `tmp2` are the same because `Partial` does the same as

```typescript
type MyPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]+?: T[K] }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAKBDATsAlogNgHgCoD4oBeKAbygG0BpKNAOygGsIQB7AMylwF0BqAfgBcXatygBfALAAoGaEhQAyqwC2EXOGgly7Vq2EBnYMnoBzADRQARikPGzU6fOgANYrAQp0WbMrUbIfBkAemCocIA9fjlNKABNdyRUDBw-dU0g6VDwqCigA)

Where `+?` is [a mapping modifier that makes a property optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers).

However, other than structural compatibility, the types express *different things*:

- `I1` implies that the regular shape of the object expected is *non-optional*. Modifying it via `Partial` means that is an exception to the regular expectations.
- `I2` is the opposite - the regular shape of the object expected is *fully optional*.

---

Illustrating with a real looking type might make it be clearer:

```typescript
interface User {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Cements the decision that all `User` objects *must* have `age` and `name` filled in. Otherwise they are not a valid `User`. However, conceivably there can be a `Partial<User>` in the system while the full set of information is still being collected. That would be a *temporary* state cannot be directly used with (for example)

```
function saveUser(user: User) { /* ... */ }
```

as that function requires a *real* user object with all the fields.

Conversely, a fully optional type might be more appropriate when any subset of the data is valid:

```
interface SurveyResult {
    score?: number;
    comment?: string;
}
```

Means that *any* survey outcome is expected. Only the score can be filled in, or the comment, or even *nothing*. Presumably, even an empty result still counts for the total surveys or similar.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer addresses the direct question you had, but you might be wondering why there are multiple ways to express optional type fields like this.

There are in fact several reasons why `Partial<I1>` may be used instead of `I2` (this is not an exhaustive list). The first and most obvious is that if you add a new field to `I1` then `Partial<I1>` will automatically contain it. This is especially important in larger projects, or for cases where the type of `I1` may be coming from an external dependency. Additionally `Partial<I1>` is more readable for other developers who may modify the code later (or yourself, when you go looking for bugs a few months down the line). `Partial<I1>` can be much more concise, especially if `I1` has a lot of fields. There is also the issue of typos and other potential problems that can appear when you are duplicating code in several places. As a general rule of thumb, you should use `Partial<Type1>` rather than manually creating a `Type2` in scenarios like the original question.