# Do I have to use question mark or Partial utility type to make a field optional using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-utility

I create below TypeScript types:

```
import { MyType, SectionTheme } from 'app/store/types';

export type Props = {
  data: MyType;
} & SectionTheme;

export type StylesProps = ThemeProps & Pick<Props, 'theme'>;
```

How do I make `theme` optional?

Do I have to go to `SectionTheme` type and add `?` like:

```
export type SectionTheme = {
  theme?: 'one' | 'two';
};
```

Or do I have to use utility [Partial type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)? And how exactly. What's the difference and what is better to use in my case?

Comment: Even if it's partial, and it's optional, it should have a question mark.

Comment: Is `theme` optional? If so, the correct thing is to mark it as optional. If it's *not* supposed to be optional in the general case but you want it optional here, then you should use the utility type.

Comment: Partial is for when you already have a type that has some required attributes, but you want to make all of them optional in this specific place

Comment: [What is the difference between Partial and Optional operator in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74266005)